# Access "not responding" for 60 sec during first sql "INSERT INTO" after opening the program/frontend

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have made an MS-Access frontend with an SQL Express backend on an separate server. The Access file is on a shared file server.

When opening the frontend and running the first sql `INSERT INTO...` using VBA, Access hangs and is "not responding" for roughly 60-90 seconds.

Following this initialization-process INSERT queries run as expected. There is no problems with SELECT or UPDATE queries. I have tested the VBA code and the stall is related to the INSERT query regardless of which form or INSERT runs first following opening of the frontend.

Primary keys in SQL Express is int and indexed.

I have tried:

- Executing the sql INSERT with DAO(rs.AddNew) and cmd.execute("INSERT INTO...").
- Set Access (Options>Client Settings>Default record locking) to "No locks" and
  disabled "Open databases by using record-level locking".
- Moving the Access file locally and executing from the desktop.
- Repair and compress database.

Unfortunately, I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Is it the first insert, or just the first command against the backend (this would imply connectivity)? What is the contents of the first insert that hangs? We probably need to see some code in order to help diagnose.

Comment: No connectivity issues - all SELECT and UPDATE queries run fine. The problem arise when running the first sql INSERT and that can be from any form. Access stalls on DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO dbo_tblUser (name, age) VALUES ('"& txtName & "', '" txtAge"')" but also with rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("dbo_tblUser", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges); With rs; .AddNew

Comment: Very unusual. The Access frontend should be local (for each user), but you already tested this. -- Check on the Sql Server: is there any activity during the wait? Is there something in the Sql Server logs? Or the Windows event logs?

Comment: For completeness: does this also happen when you insert a record with a bound form, or directly in a linked table?

Comment: SQL in comment shows missing concatenation of txtAge: `"', '" & txtAge & "')"`. Why using apostrophe delimiters for Age - is this not a number type field? Why save age instead of birthdate?

Comment: Thanks for the help. As suggested by @Andre I had a look at the sql server activity that clearly was working hard during insert. Found that the halt was associated to multiple DLOOKUPs being initiated. Have to figure out a viable alternative to DLOOKUP.